# How to check for registry value using VbScript

Tags: vbscript, registry

How can I check for registry value using VbScript?

Comment: Can you provide mode details, like an example of the registry key and value you want to check, the value type etc?

Comment: Do you need to simply read the value, check if it exists, verify the value itself or anything else?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
Function ReadFromRegistry(strRegistryKey, strDefault)
    Dim WSHShell, value

    On Error Resume Next
    Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    value = WSHShell.RegRead( strRegistryKey )

    If err.number <> 0 Then
        readFromRegistry = strDefault
    Else
        readFromRegistry = value
    End If

    Set WSHShell = Nothing
End Function
```

Usage  :

```
str = ReadfromRegistry("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Adobe\ESD\Install_Dir", "ha")
WScript.echo "returned " & str
```

[Original post](http://diablopup.blogspot.com/2007/07/vbscript-read-from-registry.html)

Answer (score 7):

Try something like this:

```
Dim windowsShell
Dim regValue
Set windowsShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
regValue = windowsShell.RegRead("someRegKey")
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

```
Dim oShell
Dim iValue

Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

iValue = oShell.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\SOMETHINGSOMETHING")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This script gets current logged in user's name & home directory:

```
On Error Resume Next

Dim objShell, strTemp
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

strTemp = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment\USERNAME"
WScript.Echo "Logged in User: " & objShell.RegRead(strTemp) 

strTemp = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment\USERPROFILE"
WScript.Echo "User Home: " & objShell.RegRead(strTemp)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
skey = "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{9A25302D-30C0-39D9-BD6F-21E6EC160475}\"
with CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    on error resume next            ' turn off error trapping
    sValue = .regread(sKey)       ' read attempt
    bFound = (err.number = 0)     ' test for success
end with
if bFound then
    msgbox "exists"
else
  msgbox "not exists" 
End If
```