# Script to create a registry key if its not there

Tags: vbscript

I want to write a script to search the registry "current user" to write a key there if it doesnt already exist, and then not to write if it does.
cheers
phil

Comment: Have you looked at this page? http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_registry_wshshell.php

Comment: thanks, but not what i'm after. i need to check if a key existsts, if not create it, if it does, do nothing. I want it to run at startup

Comment: Yeah, that link tells you how to write values...  check out this link for how to check if a value already exists: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1233754/1715829